# How to insert invalid UTF-8 sequence

Tags: character-encoding, unicode, insert

In order to test that some code handles an invalid UTF-8 sequence properly, I need to insert an invalid UTF-8 sequence into an existing text file.  However, my attempts to do so result in a valid UTF-8 sequence, not an invalid one.

The byte 0xff is always invalid in UTF-8, so I tried to insert it, following the instructions on the ["Inserting Text"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html) page of the Emacs manual:

```
c-q 377 <RET>
```

A funny-looking character got inserted into the file:

```
-OP INC       ÿ3713 SOUTHS
              ^
```

However, when I examine the contents of the file using the Unix command `od -c <path>`:

```
0001240   C  \t 303 277   3   7   1   3       S   O   U   T   H   S   H
                ^^^ ^^^
```

I can see that a valid UTF-8 sequence 303 277 (octal) has been inserted, not the single byte 377 that I tried to insert.

How can I insert an invalid UTF-8 sequence into a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some trial and error, I managed to convert `ÿ` to the byte 377 using `M-x recode-region`, specifying that it was really in `raw-text` but was interpreted as `latin-1`.

When saving the file, Emacs didn't want to save it as UTF-8, offering to save it as `raw-text` instead, which seems to have had the desired effect.

Comment: I picked this answer because it tab completes: it's easier to type.

Answer (score 9):

`C-q 377 RET` inserts the character with octal code 377 (aka LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS).  If you want to insert a byte instead of a character, you can do it with:

```
M-: (insert (unibyte-string #o377)) RET
```

As @legoscia mentioned, Emacs will probably ask you to use another coding system after inserting such a character, but you can choose `utf-8` at that prompt anyway.